# Why does my pygame collision detections not work?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

Im relatively new to Python and Pygame. I'm making a game where a circle appears at a random location on the window and you have to touch it to get a point. I've programmed it to teleport to another random location when you touch the circle. The problem is when I try to detect collision between the circle and the player it basically teleport the circle non-stop. I also made a print function which prints hi when it detects collision and it also prints non-stop. I usually try to figure out the problem, but I really don't see what Im doing wrong, I'd appreciate all help given.

```
enter code here

import pygame
import random 
vel = 2 
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
fps = 60 
win = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE) 

pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
#icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
#pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
background = pygame.image.load('Background.png') 
ghost = pygame.image.load("ghost.png") 
ghostrect = ghost.get_rect() 
circle = pygame.image.load("circle.png") 
circlerect = circle.get_rect()

def main():
    a = random.randint(0, 900)
    b = random.randint(0, 500)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True

    while run:
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and ghostrect.x + 55 <= 900:
            ghostrect.x += vel
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and ghostrect.x + 5 >= 0:
            ghostrect.x -= vel
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and ghostrect.y + 63 <= 500:
            ghostrect.y += vel
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and ghostrect.y >= 0:
            ghostrect.y -= vel
        if circlerect.colliderect(ghostrect):
            a = random.randint(0, 900)
            b = random.randint(0, 500)

        win.blit(background, (0, 0))
        win.blit(circle, (a, b))
        win.blit(ghost, (ghostrect.x + 500, ghostrect.y + 210))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You should draw the circle with `win.blit(circle, (circlerect.x, circlerect.y))`

Comment: Also, why offset the `ghostrect` when you render it? `win.blit(ghost, (ghostrect.x, ghostrect.y))`

Comment: When you get a collision, update the circle rect: `circlerect.x, circlerect.y = a, b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `ghostrect`'s value. By default, `pygame.Rect` objects position values are 0. You also have not set `circlerect`'s value, so its position is also at (0, 0).

Therefore, right now `if circlerect.colliderect(ghostrect):` will always return true.
All you need to do is to give them position values to fix the problem.

Give `ghostrect` some position. I have chosen (100, 100), that's completely up yo you.

```
 ghostrect = ghost.get_rect()
 #give the rect some position value
 ghostrect.x = 100
 ghostrect.y = 100
```

Give `circlerect` the random position instead of assigning it to `a` and `b`.

```
def main():
    #remove them
    #a = random.randint(0, 900) #this 
    #b = random.randint(0, 500) #and this
    circlerect.x = random.randint(0, 900)#add this
    circlerect.y = random.randint(0, 500)#and add this
    #...

    while run:
        #...
        if circlerect.colliderect(ghostrect):
            #remove this
            #a = random.randint(0, 900) #this 
            #b = random.randint(0, 500) #and this
    
            circlerect.x = random.randint(0, 900)#add this
            circlerect.y = random.randint(0, 500)#and add this
```

Then draw the circle at this position instead of `a` and `b`.

`win.blit(circle, (circlerect.x, circlerect.y))`